# Ansible: Using Inventory file in shell command

Tags: ansible

Playbook below. I'm trying to replace *test@ip:* with a way to pull from my inventory file the IP from a group I've created.

```
- hosts: firewall
      gather_facts: no

      tasks:

        - name: run shell script
          raw: 'sh /home/test/firewall.sh'




    - hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: no

      tasks:

        - name: Copy File to Local Machine
          shell: 'scp test@ip:/home/test/test.test  /Users/dest/Desktop'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your task like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

    - name: Copy File to Local Machine
      shell: 'scp test@{{ item }}:/home/test/test.test  /Users/dest/Desktop'
      with_items: groups['your_group_name']
```

If you want to run on all the hosts in the inventory then you can use like this:

```
with_items: groups['all']
```

Hope that will help you.

Comment: This just makes it try to run against the local host

Comment: please check it now, if you want this?